# How to change email verification code to a link for verification emails in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can we customize the content of verification emails to include a redirect link instead of code sent by SignUpOrSignin custom policies in Azure AD B2C - Identity Experience Framework?

Sample verification email:
[image: Sample verification email]

I was referring to a document below, unfortunately I could not find any workaround:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

Comment: doubt it can be done.  you used post it to [uservoice for azure ad](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory)

Comment: It is laughable that AD B2C STILL requires mobile app users to copy/type an auth code from an email into an authorisation field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At this time, it is not possible to use a redirect link instead of a verification code in Azure AD B2C's account verification experience.**

You can vote  for a suggestion on Azure Feedback portal:
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/7ebcac99-e003-ed11-a81b-6045bd853198

As per the [Azure AD B2C FAQs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs) you referenced, you can use the [company branding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding) to customize the content of verification emails.

Specifically, you can customize:

- Banner Logo: Shown at the bottom-right.
- Background color: Shown at the top.

Also, the email's signature is based on your tenant's name.

Comment: Similar discussion on https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/7ebcac99-e003-ed11-a81b-6045bd853198

Answer (score 1):

### Update in 2021

For people still referencing this post, as of June 2019, there is [sample project](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link) that gives a good overview on how to implement a magic link as sign-in. This doubles a verification of the email as well.

Comment: Please elaborate how it fits in the signup process as the sample project is about signin. Can you just take this step in question and re-use it in signup process instead of the normal email verification step?